# Unit Testing an Unhandled Exception Handler with NUnit

Tags: unit-testing, nunit, handler, unhandled-exception

I have a unit test that deliberately generates an unhandled exception. I've wired up a handler for unhandled exceptions (which I'd like to test) using:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += UnhandledExceptionHandler;
```

My test is as follows:

```
LogClient client = new LogClient();        // The handler is wired up in here

Trace.TraceInformation( "About to cause an unhandled divide-by-zero exception." );

for ( int i = 10; i > -10; --i )
{
    int j = 100 / i;
    Console.WriteLine( "i={0}, j={1}", i, j );
}

Assert.NotNull( client.UnhandledException );
```

Of course, the exception is thrown and NUnit catches it and fails the test. I've tried adding the

```
[ExpectedException(typeof(DivideByZeroException))]
```

and the test "passes" but my handler is never called and the `Assert.NotNull` is never executed. I'm wondering if it is possible to write a unit test for an unhandled exception handler. Any pointers appreciated.

I'm using NUnit 2.5.7 w/ VS 2010.

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3529917/nunit-secondary-thread-exception) suggests it is possible to set up an `UnhandledExceptionHandler` with NUnit; are you sure it is being set up in the `LogClient` constructor?  Try setting up the handler explicitly in the test.

Comment: I'm sure it's being wired up in the constructor because I've stepped through it. Just the same, I tried explicitly wiring it up in the test as you suggest with the same result. As soon as the divide-by-zero occurs, the test is failed and my handler is never called. As for the initial assumption, I don't know whether what I'm trying to do is even possible. (I'm also using ReSharper).

Comment: I hadn't found your question so I posted my own about the same problem. It's been quite a while but here is the link for future users: http://stackoverflow.com/q/9157991/82047 (for a solution, see Hans Passant's comment)

Answer (score -1):

You are not testing the handler, but the condition in which the handler should act. Concider extracting the Exceptionhandler into its own class like:

```
    internal class AnExceptionHandler
    {
        public static void UnhandledHandler(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs args)
        {
            //Do your thing and test this. 
        }
    }
```

Instantiate this class, and hook up the event up to this.

Hope this helps.

Regards, 
Morten