# AppDomain.UnhandledException handler doesn't fire in unit test

Tags: c#, testing, exception, nunit

In the code snippet below, why wouldn't the attached handler (of `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException` event) fire up when an exception is thrown in the unit test?

I'm using NUnit 2.5.10 with TestDriven.NET 3.0 on VS2010.

```
[TestFixture]
public class MyTests {

    private void CurrentDomain_UnhandledException(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e) {
        Console.WriteLine("Gotcha!");
    }

    [Test]
    public void ExceptionTest1() {
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += CurrentDomain_UnhandledException;
        throw new Exception("ExceptionInTest");
    }

}
```

Output: (No gotchas)

```
------ Test started: Assembly: WcfQueue.Test.dll ------

Test 'xxxxx.Test.MyTests.ExceptionTest1' failed: System.Exception : ExceptionInTest
    ProgramTests.cs(83,0): at xxxxx.Test.MyTests.ExceptionTest1()

0 passed, 1 failed, 0 skipped, took 1.98 seconds (NUnit 2.5.5).
```

**Update:** The purpose of this question is NOT to test .Net framework or NUnit. I just want to find out the reason why, in a unit test, the handler wouldn't fire.

Comment: What are you trying to test here. If it's the unhandledexception handler in the code you are testing, then AppDomain isn't going to be the app you are testing, it's the app tester... If you want to test exceptions google NUnit expected exceptions.

Comment: First I was trying to test whether CurrentDomain_UnhandledException worked properly, but since it never executed in my test runs; I just want to find out why it didn't. My purpose is not testing whether a method throws an exception.

Comment: Start another thread so that NUnit can't catch the exception.

Comment: Why are you testing .net? If you've a lot of free time, I can find something for you to do. :)

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks, this works! So NUnit simply executes the test in a try-catch block and doesn't have an unhandled_exception_handler in its own AppDomain. Please post this as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: Hmm reread it. You are defining a delegate for an existing eventhandler, and then pointing an exiting event at it, so yes I think you are. Presumably all your other tests are done? If you are getting somethoing out it fine, personally I remain unconvinced.

Comment: At least is wasn't serious. If you had wantied to indent by three spaces, would have meant a fight! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An exception will percolate up the call stack until you reach a try/catch block that can handle that exception, an AppDomain boundary, or the top of the stack (in that order of priorities).

If you're executing within the same AppDomain that NUnit gives you, NUnit will catch your exception. This preempts the AppDomain boundary stuff, which would have called your event.

So your test needs to create a new AppDomain and execute its code there (including the setup, which adds the event handler for AppDomain.UnhandledException). Everything should work as expected there.

Comment: I'm accepting this answer since it's the most detailed one. Creating a thread also evades NUnit's catch clause, which Hans Passant suggested.

Answer (score 2):

I guess, the event isn't fired because exception is handled. By test framework, to generate report.

Comment: Possible, but why don't I see it in the output if the framework handles it to generate report?

Comment: @henginy, what are you talking about? You *do* see it in the output -- it's right there in the output you pasted in your question: `Test 'xxxxx.Test.MyTests.ExceptionTest1' failed: System.Exception : ExceptionInTest`

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry. I was so engaged in trying to see the unhandled exception handler's output that I missed it. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know the unhandled exception event is only triggered in the default AppDomain. I think NUnit uses to execute the tests a different AppDomain which is the reason why your event does not get triggered.

Comment: I'm on the same track, NUnit does use a different AppDomain (http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=assemblyIsolation&r=2.5.7). However, MSDN says that "this event can be handled in any application domain" (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception.aspx), so here's my thinking: I could have caught this exception from my default application domain, but I cannot, so NUnit must have an UnhandledException handler in its own AppDomain.

Comment: But there's a problem, I'm registering the handler in the test itself. So it should be registered in NUnit's AppDomain..